# Prove that $ (p-1)! +1 \equiv 0 \mod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let p is a prime number.

Prove that:  $$ (p-1)! +1  \equiv 0 \:  \pmod p$$

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Comment: Note that you only need "half" of the linked question.

Comment: @quid: it's not because 2 people has the same question that it's possibly duplicate !!

Comment: @idm what is the difference in that case? (except that this is only asks for one implication as I even said)

Comment: @quid, come on man! $n$ and $p$ are totally different. What duplicate are you talking about?)

Comment: @Jihad: no, they are the same, but anyway !

Comment: @Jihad come op map they are netty iperchapgable :-)

Comment: @idm probably I should add "sarcasm".

Comment: @idm if you would explain your point a bit more I might see it.

Comment: @ quid: I haven't seen that. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider $x^{p-1}-1=0$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. What can you say about roots of the equation? (you can use [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)) Then use [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) (the last one).

Comment: I'll try to use it. thanks